# Google Home shows my smart devices loading for around 10 seconds

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I am using Google smarthome washer code to control my ESP8266 with SSR. Everything works fine but every time I open my Google Home app or Home Control in Nest Hub 2, devices are shown loading for around 10 seconds or more.
But devices from other vendors like Philips Hue are shown in 2-3 seconds.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong.

Here is the link to the code I used.
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/smarthome-washer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, my reportstate function was not updating the states of the devices due to which QUERY intent has to be called everytime I opened Google Home app which increased the loading time. Home Graph viewer is the tool to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking if you are able to handle the Query response in time and in
the correct format. Also, can you check the backend logs for the query requests and
response for the status of all the devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the log files and see if you are handling the request and response properly or having any issue in that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).